# Javascript - Show original Long number that is shown as 1.070522777034001e+29

Tags: javascript, asp.net, numbers

I doing a small asp.net project and I am using Javascript for some logic. I have a function that gives the ID of an item, however, due to the ID being too long, it is showing it to me as 1.070522777034001e+29. The problem is that, since I need to pass it to my controller, it is passing the value "1.070522777034001e+29" rather than the full value. What can I do to eliminate this please?

This is the code that I am using to display the value. The problematic field is "item[i].id". Thanks.

```
$('<ul style="list-style:none;">
   <li><span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Message </span>
       <span style="color: white;">' + item[i].message + '</span><br/>
       <span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Date</span>
       <span style="color: white;"> ' + formatDate(date) + '</span>
       <button style="float:right" id="' + item[i].id + '" onclick="postComment(' + item[i].id + ')">Add Comment</button > <hr /><li/></ul>').appendTo('#wellForPageFeed');
```

***EDIT: A small edit.. So, before passing the number as a parameter, if I print it, it prints full, however, after I pass it in the function and do a console.log() in the function, it prints it as 1.070522777034001e+29..

Comment: What .NET language are you using? If `item[i].id` is a long integer you need some formatting function rather than relying on defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `item[i].id.toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false})` to format number without scientific notation

Comment: Running `1.070522777034001e+29.toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false})` works for me. Are you sure that `item[i].id` is number?

Comment: This is the full number: 107052277703400_114128696995758

Comment: that does not look like a number to me.

Comment: I know, but why does it use it like a number? That's why I'm confused

Comment: Probably have something to do with `'+ item.id + '` operation. I am not sure what that does in ASP but in Javascript  + operator before string converts it to number.

Comment: I am using the + for string concatenation

Comment: @JohnLong `'' + item[i].id + ''` why do you plus operators here?

Comment: Because I wanted to concatenate the value.. Anyway, I posed an answer, if you're interested how I solved it. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix it but differently. After using substring to get the first part before the _ and the last part after the *, I tried to pass them, together with a "*" between them as a parameter, however it was doing the same thing. The way I solved this was to pass 2 parameters, the first part and the last, and then do string concatenation in the function.. The is shown below:

```
 for (i in item) {
      var value = item[i].id;
      var firstPart = value.substr(0, value.indexOf('_'));
      var lastPart = value.substr(value.indexOf('_') + 1, value.length);
      var date = item[i].created_time;
      $('<ul style="list-style:none;"><li><span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Message </span><span style="color: white;">' + item[i].message + '</span><br/><span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Date</span><span style="color: white;"> ' + formatDate(date) + '</span><button style="float:right" id="' + item[i].id + '" onclick="postComment(' + firstPart + ', ' + lastPart + ')">Add Comment</button > <hr /><li/></ul>').appendTo('#wellForPageFeed');
 }
```

and in the function:

```
function postComment(postIdFirstPart, postIdLastPart) {

    var postId = postIdFirstPart + '_' + postIdLastPart;
    console.log("a " + postId)
```

}